# How to create a proxy connection on mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, proxy, rds

My company is using http proxy connection to connect through the internet. I am trying to connect to my RDS MySQL instance on AWS by using MySQL Workbench. However, I get failed error. I need to configure my workbench to connect through my company http proxy.

Any suggests how?

Best Regards
Fady

Comment: What have you try so far, did you ask the admin to allow connection to your RDS Mysql port?

Comment: we don't have admin, it is a big company and we have http url for the proxy.

Comment: There is no way you can make you local mysql client talk to RDS server behind a corporate firwall without talking with "some" admin,  check out VPN requirement, etc.

Comment: I got an exception by our admins and want to pass the proxy settings which they told me to use further to MySQL Workbench. I think this is what @FadyBerty question targets at, isn't it? On Windows 10, I cannot find any place where proxy settings can be specified within MySQL Workbench. Is that true? Thanks for any hints!